# Loading javascripts from external domain with few seconds delay after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, delay, external

I did a lot of research on the internet, but still cannot find the answer to my problem. I am basically trying the execute two external java-scripts (hosted on external domain) with 5-10 seconds delay after my page has fully loaded. I am already using a delay script to load a google map into a IFRAME, and it works fine, but don't know how to also delay the loading of the two external js files. Please see image on the url below for coding.

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  document.write(...);
  document.write(...);
}, 10000)
```

Answer (score 0):

loading of script acc. to the loading of document is very necessary as whole functionality depends on it, instead of making a hard guess you can EventListener like document.addEventListener("load",yourFunction,false);
this statement execute after finishing the loading of document.